# Virtually shifting an array

Tags: c#, arrays

I am using C#.
I have an array of size 10. I want to pass it to a function, but only from the second element. In C, this is how I would implement it

myfunc( myarray + 1 )

Effectively I am virtually shifting the array / deleting the first element.

How do I implement this in C# ?

Answer (score 4):

If you're using .NET 3.5, the easiest is to use Skip(1) then convert back to an array.

```
myFunc(myArray.Skip(1).ToArray());
```

If performance is an issue then you will either need to construct a new array manually or change your function to accept an index parameter.

Comment: Great, that works. I cant modify the function because it is part of another library and performance is not an issue.
Thanks!!

Comment: +1 I was going to suggest Array.CopyTo(newArray, 1),but the extension method approach is easier to understand, perhaps with some negligible? performance cost.

Comment: Now there are two ways. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

There are four options here:

1. Pass in an index, and use that in your function
2. Make your function use `IEnumerable<T>` instead of an array (`T[]`), then use `myArray.Skip(1)`.
3. Use skip, but convert back to an array.  This copies the array elements, however.
4. Use an [`ArraySegment<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d.aspx) instead of an array for your function.

This really depends on whether you have control over the usage within your `myfunc` function.  If that function must accept an array, and you can't pass an index, you're going to be stuck creating a copy of the array.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass an index to the function also, and only access the array beginning at that index.